# Code is working in Windows but not in Linux! Why? [Simple pointer problem]

Tags: c, windows, linux, pointers, struct

This is a working code snippet of a transportation problem (Removed the actual function. Only input and output functions are here. And BTW, it's incorrect)

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct transport
{
    int cost;
    int alloc;
}TRAN;

void problem_input      (TRAN **, int *, int *, int, int);
void problem_display    (TRAN **, int *, int *, int, int);

int main()
{
    int n_dest;
    int n_org;
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("\n\n\tEnter Number Of Destinations          : ");
    scanf("%d", &n_dest);

    printf("\n\n\tEnter Number Of Origins(Sub-stations) : ");
    scanf("%d", &n_org);

    TRAN ** array   = (TRAN **)calloc(n_org, sizeof(TRAN *));

    int * dest      = (int *)calloc(n_dest, sizeof(int));
    int * origins   = (int *)calloc(n_org, sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < n_org; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (TRAN *)calloc(n_dest, sizeof(TRAN *));
    }

    problem_input       (array, dest, origins, n_dest, n_org);
    problem_display     (array, dest, origins, n_dest, n_org);

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}

void problem_input      (TRAN ** array, int * dest, int * origins, int n_dest, int n_org)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("\n\n\tEnter The Amount Of Supplies Required At The Destinations : ");

    for(i = 0; i < n_dest; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\tDestination %d : ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &dest[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\tEnter The Amount Of Supplies Available At The Origins     : ");

    for(i = 0; i < n_org; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\tOrigin %d : ", (i+1));
        scanf("%d", &origins[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\tEnter The Cost Matrix : ");

    for(i = 0; i < n_org; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t\tOrigin %d", (i+1));

        for(j = 0; j < n_dest; j++)
        {
            printf("\n\n\t\t\tDestination %d : ", (j+1));

            scanf("%d", &array[i][j].cost);
        }
    }
}

void problem_display    (TRAN ** array, int * dest, int * origins, int n_dest, int n_org)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("\n\n\tThe Given Transportation Problem : ");

    for(i = 0; i < n_org; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t");

        for(j = 0; j < n_dest; j++)
        {
            printf("\t%d", array[i][j].cost);
        }

        printf("\t[%d]", origins[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\t");

    for(i = 0; i < n_dest; i++)
    {
        printf("\t[%d]", dest[i]);
    }
}
```

This much was working fine in Windows but displayed incorrect output in Linux. (I use Windows at home but Linux at college. Imagine how I felt when I'm getting a wrong output in front of my professor. But she was none the wiser.)

For example my input for 'cost' in `TRAN ** array` was

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

but the output was coming like

```
1 2 4
4 5 7
7 8 9
```

My error was during creation of the structure. I create 2D arrays like this (very standard)

```
    TRAN ** array   = (TRAN **)calloc(n_org, sizeof(TRAN *));

    for(i = 0; i < n_org; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (TRAN *)calloc(n_dest, sizeof(TRAN));
    }
```

But by mistake, I did this in the for loop

```
    for(i = 0; i < n_org; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (TRAN *)calloc(n_dest, sizeof(TRAN *));
    }
```

That is `sizeof(TRAN *)` instead of `sizeof(TRAN)`

So my question is, why didn't this glaring mistake show in Windows?

Comment: No both college and home pc = 32 Bit OS

Comment: Home = XP SP3 32 Bit and in college we telnet to a server so can't say. It's just Linux

Answer (score 1):

What's likely happening is that types are of different sizes on different operating systems. It might turn out that on Windows, sizeof(TRAN) == sizeof(TRAN*) (based on the elements inside TRAN and sizeof(int)) whereas on linux, this obviously isn't the case.

Comment: sizeof(TRAN *) = 4
sizeof(TRAN ) = 8
I'm getting this in Windows, but still there is no error

Comment: I'm also getting the same result in Ubuntu (4 bytes an 8 bytes). I'm using virtual box if it's of any help

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of `int` versus the size of a `TRAN*`.

If you're "lucky" to compile on a 64bit platform with 32bit `int`s, and that doesn't have padding in `struct TRAN`, then `sizeof(TRAN*) == sizeof(TRAN)`.

If you're on a 32bit platform with 32bit `int`s. That doesn't hold anymore.

Comment: Home = XP SP3 32 Bit and in college we telnet to a server so can't say. It's just Linux (Prolly 32 bit)

Comment: sizeof(TRAN *) = 4 sizeof(TRAN ) = 8
Got this result in both XP and Linux(Virtual Box) at home

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER CHANGED**

if you look at your code you have not used the `alloc` component. Now when you allocate the structure it takes `2n` bytes where `n` is the size of integer. You only access the `cost` component. Also because you have allocated the `TRAN *` instead of `TRAN` when doing `array[i][j]` the array arithmatic does `*(*(array + sizeof (int *)) + sizeof (TRAN *))` but you wanted `*(*(array + sizeof (int *)) + sizeof (TRAN))` in which case actually when you access the two `cost` components in the two structures they are actually accessed in adjacent locations. So the memory access is perfectly right. because you only access the only one component and read at the same location where you have written with the same array notation so you get the same output as you have input . I guess if write both the `alloc` and `cost` components then you would have only the value get stored which you stored the latest for each `i`, `j`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with memory protection, and no standard-conformant compiler should produce an error message given the OP's code.

Comment: Not a very good guess... No one uses Turbo C++ 3.1 anymore. That compiler has been obsolete for *at least* 15 years.

Comment: not a bad guess also because here at our place, lots of people does not use any compiler except TurboC++ 3.1

Comment: Wow, you have a time machine? What do you do with all those 16-bit executables? Creating a virtual machine just to compile and test code seems tiring... What do you do with all that useless knowledge of the MS-DOS memory model? How do you ignore the *major* changes in the C++ standard introduced since Turbo C++ 3.1, which wasn't even compliant when it was initially released 20 years ago.

Comment: cool down :) i am telling "at our place, lots of people does not use any compiler except TurboC++ 3.1" i personally do not use. I am using gcc 4.3 . The Turbo C++ 3.1 is used in college to make people start C programming. Now i cannot instruct the instructors to change.

Comment: @All I'm using Code::Blocks 10.05, GNU GCC compiler